# Adding orientation in media query in MUI

Tags: css, reactjs, responsive-design, material-ui, media-queries

I am using MUI along with React in my project. I am using MUI breakpoints to style iPad resolution separately like below

```
  contentBox:{
        width:"10%",
        paddingLeft:"10px",
        [theme.breakpoints.between(768, 1024)]: {
            width:"15%",
            paddingLeft:"8px",
          }
    }
```

The above works fine in iPad portrait. now I was to add orientation for iPad landscape like how to do with normal media queries so that I can style in iPad landscape resolution as well. Any inputs will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

try standard material ui sizes :
xl, lg, md, sm, xs
for example :
[theme.breakpoints.down("md")] or [theme.breakpoints.up("sm")]

Answer (score 0):

For detecting landscape orientation you can try adding `and (orientation: landscape)`.
Ex:

> ```
>  contentBox:{
>     width:"10%",
>     paddingLeft:"10px",
>     [`${theme.breakpoints.between(768, 1024)} and (orientation: landscape)`]: {
>         width:"15%",
>         paddingLeft:"8px",
>     }
> }
> ```

or use media query inside media query:

> ```
>  contentBox:{
>     width:"10%",
>     paddingLeft:"10px",
>     '@media (orientation: landscape)': {
>         [theme.breakpoints.between(768, 1024)]: {
>             width:"15%",
>             paddingLeft:"8px",
>         }
>     }
> }
> ```

But either way it is recommended you use the mui breakpoints (xs, sm, md, lg, xl) which you can configure. If you setup `sm = 768` and `md = 1024`, then your `between()` would be something like: `theme.breakpoints.between(sm, md)`.